# What GCP service(s) can be used to stream video on demand?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to make a website like YouTube. I am looking for a Google Cloud Platform equivalent of [Video on Demand on Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/video-on-demand-on-aws/) if it exists

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Google answer is to store video in a Google Drive.  You can write new files to Google Drive using API.  If you upload one of the supported formats, it will be processed ready for playing.

Supported formats are:

- WebM files (Vp8 video codec; Vorbis Audio codec)
- MPEG4, 3GPP, and MOV files (h264 and MPEG4 video codecs; AAC audio codec)
- AVI (MJPEG video codec; PCM audio)
- MPEGPS (MPEG2 video codec; MP2 audio)
- WMV
- FLV (Adobe - FLV1 video codec, MP3 audio)
- MTS
- OGG

See also:

- [How to Share Videos Through Google Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pa79HVAAbX4)
- [How and why to move your media to Google Drive](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-and-why-to-move-your-media-to-google-drive/)
- [Google Drive API Video Library](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/videos)
- [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/)
- Google Search: [google drive video](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+drive+video)

Comment: Interesting solution. There isn't much documentation around streaming videos from Drive.

Comment: I did some more searching and there appears to be some nuggets.  I updated the answer with some more potentially useful links.